# How to create a separate column for each related field value while exporting data via django-import-export

Tags: django, django-import-export

I have a `PaymentRecord` model which stores user payments for event tickets. I have a `TicketPurchase` model which records which tickets were purchased by which `PaymentRecord`. So my models look something like this -

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class PaymentRecord(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='payments')
    payment_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)
    # various payment details and user identifiers

class TicketPurchase(models.Model):
    payment_record = models.ForeignKey(PaymentRecord, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tickets')
    tier_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    ticket_count = models.IntegerField()
```

Each event that I am selling tickets for has a few "tiers", like Silver, Gold, Platinum (Each event has different names for tiers). When I export all the `PaymentRecord` objects for a particular event, I want to somehow get a list of all the "tiers" that exist in the queryset being exported, and then have a separate column for each tier showing how many tickets for that tier were purchased by a payment.

So I want my output to be something like this -

| Event Name | Payment Time | Silver Tickets | Gold Tickets | Platinum Tickets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Event 1 | # time 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| Event 1 | # time 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

How can I achieve this using `django-import-export`?

Right now I am using a `ModelResource` to export a summary of the different tiers purchased in a single column, as so -

```
class PaymentRecordsResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = PaymentRecord
    ticket_count = Field(column_name='Tickets')

    def dehydrate_ticket_count(self, obj):
        tickets = ''
        for ticket in obj.tickets.all():
            tickets += f'{ticket.tier_name}: {ticket.ticket_count}\n'
        if not tickets:
            tickets = '-'
        return tickets.strip()
```

However, I want to create a separate column for each tier. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

In case you're in a hurry here is the resourse for your desired table.

```py
from django.db.models import Sum

class PaymentRecordsResource(resource.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = PaymentRecord
        fields = ('event__name', 'payment_time', 'silver_ticket_count', 'gold_ticket_count', 'platinum_ticket_count')
    silver_ticket_count = Field(column_name='Silver Tickets')
    gold_ticket_count = Field(column_name='Gold Tickets')
    platinum_ticket_count = Field(column_name='Platinum Tickets')


    def dehydrate_silver_ticket_count(self, obj):
        return self.get_ticket_count(obj, 'silver')

    def dehydrate_gold_ticket_count(self, obj):
        return self.get_ticket_count(obj, 'gold')

    def dehydrate_platinum_ticket_count(self, obj):
        return self.get_ticket_count(obj, 'platinum')

    def get_ticket_count(self, obj, tier_name, default=0):
        return obj.tickets.filter(tier_name=tier_name).aggregate(Sum('ticket_count'))['ticket_count__sum'] or default
```

---

This is how i got to this resource. First we need to get the fields we want:

```py
silver_ticket_count = Field(column_name='Silver Tickets')
gold_ticket_count = Field(column_name='Gold Tickets')
platinum_ticket_count = Field(column_name='Platinum Tickets')
```

In the same step we can exclude the fields we don't want (like `id` or `event_id`) by specifying excactly the fields we want to display in the `meta` class

```py
class Meta:
    model = PaymentRecord
    fields = ('event__name', 'payment_time', 'silver_ticket_count', 'gold_ticket_count', 'platinum_ticket_count')
```

`payment_time` points to the field of the model. `silver_ticket_count` points to the field we defined earlier in the resource and `event__name` points to the relationship of the model to its linked `Event` and its name. Read more about how this works in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Then i set up a method to get the value of the field.

```py
def dehydrate_silver_ticket_count(self, obj):
    return obj.tickets.filter(tier_name='platinum').aggregate(Sum('ticket_count'))['ticket_count__sum'] or 0
```

`obj.tickets.filter(tier_name=''platinum')` gets all tickets related to the `PaymentRecord` with the platinum tier. Aggregation is a somewhat complicated topic you can read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/aggregation/). For our purposes this means it sums up all tickets with the platinum tier on the database level and returns the value.

Because this lookup is basically the same for gold and platinum i decided to put it in it's own method.

Note: We are making three extra hits on the DB.

```py
def get_ticket_count(self, obj, tier_name, default=0):
    return obj.tickets.filter(tier_name=tier_name).aggregate(Sum('ticket_count'))['ticket_count__sum'] or default
```

Now we need to populate the remaining methods to get the value for all tiers.

```py
def dehydrate_silver_ticket_count(self, obj):
    return self.get_ticket_count(obj, 'silver')

def dehydrate_gold_ticket_count(self, obj):
    return self.get_ticket_count(obj, 'gold')

def dehydrate_platinum_ticket_count(self, obj):
    return self.get_ticket_count(obj, 'platinum')
```

---

If you only have theses three tiers of tickets and they never change i suggest you add [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) to your ModelField to limit the value `tier_name` can have to only these three choices.

Comment: Column naming and column ordering is left as an exercise for the reader. [django-import-export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#resources)

Comment: Thanks for this, but the problem is that not all events have the same 3 tiers. Some events have Silver, Gold, and Platinum, but some have tiers with completely different names. However, all events have a fixed set of tiers that doesn't change. What I wanted was a way to find out all the names of the tiers that exist in the queryset being exported and then create a new column for each tier. Sorry about the confusion, I've updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: I've had a poke around but sadly i couldn't get it to work with your new requirements. Best of luck to you!